# Running a vboxmanage clonemedium from a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, virtualbox

This is probably nothing but I'm not able to make a simple VirtualBox `vboxmanage clonemedium` command run correctly in a PS script.

Seams like there's a quote issue. Tried a lot, got no results.
My paths to the source and destination files are previously stored into 2 variables.
If I trace them, they are perfectly OK.

```cs
$sourceFile = "C:\VirtualBox VMs\OdooV8-Clone1\Odoo-imchem-64b-Clone1.vdi\"
$destinationFile = "E:\TestVMbackup\$thedate\OdooV8-imchem-clone_$theShortDate.vdi"

vboxmanage clonemedium disk '$sourceFile' '$DestinationFile' --variant Fixed
```

This last try returns:

> VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find file for the medium 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\$sourceFile' (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee IUnknown

Using:

```
vboxmanage clonemedium disk "$sourceFile" "$DestinationFile" --variant Fixed
```

was worst.

Comment: `'$sourceFile'` - variables aren't expanded in single quoted strings. This literally says the disk is called "dollar sourcefile". Same with the destination file. If you're just using the variables, don't quote them in that line. "*was worst.*" - worst how, worst why?

Comment: using double quotes gives:
Usage:

VBoxManage clonemedium      [disk|dvd|floppy] <uuid|inputfile> <uuid|outputfile>
                            [--format VDI|VMDK|VHD|RAW|<other>]
                            [--variant Standard,Fixed,Split2G,Stream,ESX]
                            [--existing]


Syntax error: Mandatory output file parameter missing

I also tried:
    $cloneparam = "$sourceFile $DestinationFile --variant Fixed"
    Write-Host "cloneparam: $cloneparam"

Comment: I don't know why it says the output file is missing, but your input file ends with a backslash, which looks like it's going to be a problem because that specifies it's a directory. What's in `$thedate` and `$TheShortDate` ?

Comment: thank you.. you point it!

$thedate and shortdate are string previously built to name the folders.
cloneparam: C:\VirtualBox VMs\OdooV8-Clone1\Odoo-imchem-64b-Clone1.vdi\ E:\TestVMbackup\14.décembre.2017\OdooV8-imchem-c
lone_14-12-2017.vdi --variant Fixed

However even without the trailing backslash I'm still having the mandatory file parameter missing error

Comment: ok the trailing backslash aways AND using again my first syntax:
vboxmanage clonemedium disk "$sourceFile" "$DestinationFile" --variant Fixed

is now ok